# Shapefile for India which is up-to-date to display regional borders

Tags: data, india

I need a shapefile for **India** which is up-to-date to display the regional borders. By up-to-date (in 2014), I mean that it **includes Telangana** as a state. Many shapefiles that I downloaded do not have Telangana as a state as it was partitioned a month ago, it is displayed as part of Andhrapradesh.

So I need the latest shapefile.

Answer (score 6):

Hava a look at OpenStreetMap. Take a look at this relation: http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3250963 where Telangana is included.
You can download OSM land polygons from here: http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons or daily updated data from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html

Answer (score 1):

take a look at what I've got here - https://github.com/geohacker/india. Contains District, State and Taluk level shapefiles for India, based on the GADM data.

Answer (score 0):

The datameet group has released a set of shapefiles, which includes the state of Telengana as separate from Andhra Pradesh: http://github.com/datameet/maps/

The data is shared under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 India license.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find QGIS project which includes Telangana. "Shapefile" contains .shape file GeoJSON and TopoJSON as well.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByLjiBJ1xOpueWpmbC1yOV9sc2M?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

http://projects.datameet.org/maps/

Found this to be a good source.
Community Created Maps of India sourced from different government websites which are freely available to all the Indians. Here we have digitized them, cleaned them, added appropriate attributes so it can be used by all the researchers, students etc.:

All the boundaries are available in geojson or shapefile (WGS84, EPSG4326) format. The below table gives you the status of the data as we clean and upload. Data is not perfect there as many errors both in data and boundaries. You can contribute by sending the pull requests. Please use the census names when correcting the attributes and geojson for shapes. Refer CONTRIBUTING for ways to contribute.